# XPath doesn't locate element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want to scrape links from this page.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=food+recepies

```
WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id=\"video-title\"]"));
WebElement w2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*a[@id='video-title']"));
WebElement w3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer']"));
WebElement w4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3/a"));

String link = w1.getAttribute("href");
```

None of these works for me.

```
Error: Unable to locate element: //a[@id="video-title"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the title.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='video-title']"));
```

However, there are 27 of them. So, you might want to use

```
List<WebElement> plants = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@id='video-title']"));
```

Another thing is that you might want to wait until the elements are visible, enabled, clickable, etc., on the page. For this, you need to do something like the following:

```
WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
     .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(By.xpath("//a[@id='video-title']")));
```

Comment: It should but it does not. org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //a[@id='video-title']

Comment: WebDriverWait solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Den sorry, I just saw this. Always remember that you need to wait until the page loads before attempting to locate a component on the page. There are other forms of "wait" that you should research.